# Why should we create Model fields in Django for MongoDB?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-models, djongo

I have worked on `RDBMS` with `Django`. I'm familiar with Models, Model fields in `Django`.

We are looking for a better way of storing large documents in database.

We came across `MongoDB` and found that the collections in `MongoDB` doesn't have a schema to store documents.

But I found plenty of tutorials where they mention `Model fields` when working with `MongoDB` in `Django`. I searched a lot for this but couldn't find why they are still mentioning model fields in Models in `Django`.

Why are we still creating `Model fields (columns)` when there is no specific schema for `MongoDB` collection?

Comment: Probably just because Python/Django still needs to know what to expect when you create/fetch an object, otherwise each object basically just becomes a dictionary. I haven't used MongoDB from Django, so it's possible you might be able to use it without a schema/model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongo Schemas are optional. However, they provide the following advantages:

- schema validation (e.g. data types, specific validation for each field)
- consistent data structure (e.g. might help while retrieving data)

Further recources which might be interesting:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/